# Why session custom data lost after refresh in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.1.5, sessions

I need to save data in session on one page and retrieve same data on multiple pages. **After saving the data when i refresh page Or redirect to another page data flush off** . Can somebody explain me why it's happening? What can do to fix this?

I have tried with all types of sessions in magento2(**customer,checkout,backend,catalog**) also `phpsession($_SESSION)` without any luck.

am using **Magento 2.1.7** with **Luma Theme**.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For Catalog, Checkout, Customer and other Magento session like

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Session
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
\Magento\Customer\Model\Session
```

Because Magento 2 is no longer using **core session** like in magento 1.

```
protected $customerSession;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession, 
    ....
){
    ....
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    ....
}
```

To set and get the value of session.

```
$this->customerSession->setCustomerName('Bob'); //Set Value
$this->customerSession->getCustomerName(); // Get Value
$this->customerSession->unsCustomerName(); // Unset Value
```

You can use above **Factory** method by creating function or directly by using **objectManager**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerSession->setCustomerName('Bob');
$customerSession->getCustomerName();
```

Comment: Already tried this, didn't worked. I mentioned above.

Comment: you want to get it in PHTML file?

Comment: No just in controller. Saving data in one controller and retrieve at multiple places .

Comment: multiple places like other controllers ? right

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: please check my updated answer

Comment: Already tried this approach as well without any success. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Check if your session cookie is properly resend. You might misconfigured cookie domain

Comment: This worked for me "\Magento\Persistent\Model\Session" and "\Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface"

Answer (score 0):

You may have exceeded the string length limit for storing data in the session. Just increase this value from Magento admin panel (**Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Security**).

#### Details:

Data which Magento saving each time (almost on each request) looks like this (it is a part of real data):

[image: session data example]

As you can see at the bottom of screenshot it is **285934** chars length. But Magento (2.4.1 in my case) has own properties named "Max Session Size in Admin" and "Max Session Size in Storefront" which add limits to the maximum allowed size of that string. Default value of that settings is **256000** and it is less than size of real data in my case.

[image: Settings in admin panel]

What Magento does? It adding notification message in the log file, and save nothing new... but did not delete old value.

Here is that part of code from `./vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler.php`:

[image: Saving data from session]

Checked in debugger:

[image: Size from debugger]